# Row level security in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: database, azure-cosmosdb, database-security

I have a cosmos db system with a user table. Now I'm develop a client app that connects to cosmos db directly by cosmos sdk (iOS).
I'd like to add a security layer to make sure a user can't access other user records, some like `select * from User c` 
Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens), Cosmos db has two types of keys:

[image]

For your need, you need to give up `master keys`, use `resource tokens` instead. It could provide access to specific document.

So my idea is:

When you create every row of data, you need to generate resource token which maps this user and store it as an additional column. Then when a user query data, he should provide his resource token (as security layer) to authenticate his permission of filtering data. Not every one uses master keys, it can't control the data isolation. Please refer to the model listed in above link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that I need to generate the partition key for each user record and set the resource token permission tie to partition key to prevent query on other rows?

Comment: @R4j Yeah,that's what i mean.Then the user can't query data without providing properly resource token.Hope it could give you some clues.

Comment: Great, thanks for you help. I found this example https://github.com/adamhockemeyer/Azure-Functions---CosmosDB-ResourceToken-Broker that uses your suggestion. I'll try now